# How can I find two strings $m_1$ and $m_2$, knowing that I know $m_1 \oplus m_2$?

Tags: stream-cipher, xor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse)

I recently started to follow the cryptography class of Dan Boneh on [coursera.org](http://www.coursera.org) and the first part is talking about stream ciphers.

In general, we have an encryption which works as follows:

$$c = E(k,m) = m \oplus k$$

and $$D(k,c)=c \oplus k = m \oplus k \oplus k = m \oplus 0 =m $$

Where $k$ is the key $m$ is the message and $c$ is the cypher.

For this method, the key should be used only once. Assuming the same $k$ is used twice to produce both $c_1=E(k,m_1)$ and $c_2=E(k,m_2)$, then we could do

$$c_1 \oplus c_2 = m_1 \oplus k \oplus m_2 \oplus k=m_1 \oplus \underbrace{k \oplus k}_0 \oplus m_2 = m_1 \oplus m_2 $$

Now the class claims that is messages are in English and encoded ASCII, knowing $m_1 \oplus m_2$ is sufficient to get $m_1$ and $m_2$. However, I have no idea how this is possible.

Can somebody help me out our provide me with a good book/resource where I could find the method?