# AES-CTR key reuse attack with same IV and known plain text

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis

this is from an IT Security exercise which my friend and me cannot solve.

Given

- 2 AES-CTR stream-cipher encrypted files
- Same known initalizing vector
- Same (unkown) key
- Same 128bit Counter initialized with 0
- Files are .png so there is known plain text in both files (the file header)

Our approach was to use the known equivalence of

$E(A) \oplus E(B) = A \oplus B$

From there the only option we see is to brute force $A$ and $B$ for the known $\oplus$ product.

Is there a smarter way to get $A$, $B$? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must IV/key-pairs not be reused in CTR mode?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/why-must-iv-key-pairs-not-be-reused-in-ctr-mode) That is two-time pad.

Comment: I agree, because there aren't any other mathematical equivalences to work with, so you are left guessing the bit values within $A$ and $B$ (not sure if you'd call that brute force though). How to do that depends on the type of message - in this case PNG pixels. That you have the header doesn't make it any easier.

Comment: Comment below if you have a generic method of getting the original values within PNG files that are XOR'ed together. Happy to reopen for that.