# How to decrypt a text which is ciphered same length key?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I have ten piece of ciphered texts. I know that they ciphered with a same-length key. Any idea how I can decrypt the ciphertexts? What kind of algorithms should I use? What are the points of taking care of 'XORing' these texts with each other and space character?
(text ciphered with the asymmetric key)
should we use the frequency analysis?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. Your question is missing some details – which encrytion algorithm is in use? If it is some misused [tag:one-time-pad], look other questions with that tag.

Comment: Didn't know Crypto I was running again at Coursera...

Comment: first of all i am student in cs and got this take-home. As i said  have only ten short ciphered text and also information of those ciphered with the same key...(XOR cipher and a key). That's all.

Comment: You are looking for how to attack one time pad reuse. There is a lot of information already on this site for that. Have a look around.

Comment: See also: [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse)

Comment: thank you very much for your advices. i found what i am searching for. it was "many time pad cipher text attacks ";)