# One Time Pad small key multiple times

Tags: cryptanalysis, one-time-pad

i'm ask what is the wrong if i used small key multiple times in OTP .?

for example :

key .. . 10 10 10 10 10 10

plain .. 11 01 01 11 01 00

cipher 01 11 11 01 11 10

what can hacker know about plain text in this situations??

Comment: You may want to note that this (example) is equivalent to encrypting 6 different messages with the same OTP-key. Does [this other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2249/23623) now answer yours?

Answer (score 1):

From your example, the adversary would know that the first bit and the third bit in the plaintext are different (bit shift of one another) since the first bit and the third bit in the ciphertext are different (bit shift of one another).