# Stream Cipher : Never use stream cipher key more than once

Tags: stream-cipher, key-reuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse)
>   [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse)

Denote C is cipher text, m is message, and PRG(k) is a psuedo randomize generator, generate an key.

Because we have :

```
C1 = m1 xor PRG(k)
C2 = m2 xor PRG(k)

--> C1 xor C2 = m1  xor m2
```

So, this is a problem because if m1 and m2 is a real text (a text that is in normal life)  and use ASCII, you can predict m1 and m2 if you know `m1 xor m2`.

I don't understand last statement so much. Why we can predicted m1 and m2 when we just know `m1 xor m2` ? I have though some additional information, such as in normal text, `E` is the most appearance character, after that is `T`... but I still cannot explain.

Thanks :)

Comment: There is also this: [Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse)

Comment: @hqt, take a look at the two questions linked to above. They should answer your question. Therefore I am going to close your question. If after reading them, you feel that they do not address your question, please edit the question, explain why, and flag it to be reopened.