# Random unique key per message, safe to use key as IV?

Tags: rsa, aes, cbc, initialization-vector

The overall setup is that I am using RSA public key encryption, and because the messages are big instead of encrypting the entire message via RSA I am encrypting a random AES-128 key with the PK and then encrypting the message with that in AES-CBC.

The AES key is randomly generated for each message. Questions:

1. Is it safe to use the key as the IV of the CBC? The rationale here is the key is unique and random for each message and I'm not seeing a problem. The key is used in 3 places thus: the encryption itself, then as an IV, then again concatenated with the encrypted message's hash and everything hashed again as a MAC.
2. Do I still need to do any random padding on the IM itself? The key and IV are already unique and random.

Comment: [AES key equal to IV (CBC mode)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31583/aes-key-equal-to-iv-cbc-mode)

Comment: Why are you inventing your own MAC? There are plenty of authenticated encryption algos. And why are you reusing the key, instead of simply hardcoding the IV?

Comment: You might as well use the 128 bit output of a hash of the key, e.g.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the abbreviation "IM" in this context. Could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to use the key as the IV of the CBC?

CodesInChaos has answered this sufficiently in the Q&A he linked ([*AES key equal to IV (CBC mode)*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31596/23623)) and the TL;DR is: It's risky, but not directly exploitable.

> Do I still need to do any random padding on the IM itself?

Hybrid encryption modes generally don't need random message padding as the randomness is already encapsulated in the key.

---

Now for some other issues with your scheme:

- **You're using concatenation and hashing as the MAC.** More precisely your MAC construction is $\tau=H(H(M)\parallel K)$ is [*potentially* broken](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1070/23623).
- **You're using CBC.** Using CBC in newly deployed system is highly discouraged, especially due to padding oracle attacks and the likes which are only an issue in block-based encryption modes.
- **You're not using [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption).** Rolling your own mode of encryption and authentication is dangerous without proper knowledge and formal security reductions. Using a proper mode like [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), [OCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode) or [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) is really recommended and will ease implementation and use proven-secure constructions.
- **Your RSA encryption is probably risky to say the least.** If I'm reading your question right you may be using straight, textbook RSA encryption of the 128-bit secret. However this is highly susceptible to brute-force attacks which can recover this secret in roughly $2^{64}$ steps.

Comment: The last paragraph has its [own explaining Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42605/23623) now.