# How to recover small messages from textbook RSA?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack, deterministic-encryption

In [the answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42601/23623) to the question [*Random unique key per message, safe to use key as IV?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42596/23623) it was claimed that one can recover a random 128-bit textbook-RSA encrypted value using about $2^{64}$ steps.

How and why does this attack work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I did not come up originally with this attack, but rather it was first described in [*"Why Textbook ElGamal and RSA Encryption
Are Insecure"* by Boneh, Joux and Nguyen (PDF).](https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/archive/fr/sciences/fichiers/lcr/bojong00.pdf)**

This answer will give a summary of the attack, similar to what is documented in [*Introduction to Modern Cryptography* by Katz and Lindell](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html).

First for the actual attack:
Let $c=m^e\bmod N$ be given as well as $(N,e)$ and let $m<2^l$ for some $l\in\mathbb N$. Then there exists $m=r\cdot s$ with $r,s<2^{\alpha\cdot l}$ for some $1/2<\alpha<1$ with decent probability:

1. Set $T:=2^{\alpha\cdot l}$.
2. For all $r$ from $1$ to $T$ compute and store $x_i=r^e\bmod N$.
3. Sort the pairs $(r,x_i)$ by the second component.
4. For all $s$ from $1$ to $T$ check (e.g. using binary search) whether $c\cdot s^{-e}\bmod N=x_i$ for some $i$, if so return $r\cdot s \bmod N$ as the message $m$.

(If $s^{-e}$ cannot be computed, then $s$ shares a non-trivial common divisor with $N$, and so one can trivially factor $N$ by calculating $\gcd(s,N)$.)

Now for the run-time of this algorithm:
One needs about $2^{\alpha\cdot l}$ modular exponentiations for step 2, $\mathcal O(l\cdot 2^{\alpha\cdot l})$ for step three and about $\mathcal O(l\cdot 2^{\alpha\cdot l})$ for step four. So overall one does get away with "little more" than $2^{\alpha\cdot l}$ steps. Given that there's at least some chance (a few percent) that $\alpha=1/2$ will work, this would result in an attack with about $2^{l/2}$ run-time.

Note that steps 1 to 3 above don't depend on the ciphertext $c$, so they can be done in advance, and the resulting table reused for several ciphertext.

As for why this attack works, note that we effectively brute-force factor the message by exploiting the homomorphic property of RSA and that $c=m^e=(rs)^e=r^es^e\bmod N$.

Comment: The details of the probabilities that certain $\alpha$ will work are documented in the linked paper.

Comment: Would it not be more convenient to store $x_i = r^e \bmod N$ in the table, and look up $c \cdot s^{-e} \bmod N$ for each $s$? That way, the table can be precomputed once and reused for multiple messages. In fact, at a glance, that seems to be what the attack in section 5 of the linked paper is actually doing.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I CW'ed the A (originally planned to do it, then thought the other way and finally forgot that I made just about 0 contribution here). Feel free to optimize it :)