# Calculating characters from the sum of ASCII pairs

Tags: encryption

I have a series of messages (limited to only a-z and A-Z) that are encoded such that the sum is taken of every two ASCII values and concatenated. For instance, the message `hello` would be decomposed into the pairs `he`, `ll`, and `o` which would then become `104 + 101`, `108 + 108`, and `111` which finally is output as  `205216111`. Each pair is guaranteed to be 3 digits by zero-padding.

Is it possible to trivially decode this final number back into the plaintext? The words are in plain English and each word is capitalized. So far I have attempted to enumerate all possible permutations and identify words from a dictionary list but this has proven to be rather tedious with short messages alone.

Comment: "this has proven to be rather tedious with short messages alone" - surely, you have a computer doing the searching, don't you?

Comment: @poncho Of course, It is just that the possible pairs are many in number and while a dictionary attack can identify words it cannot discern sentences: small articles often end up making a word soup that makes a totally automated approach nigh impossible

Comment: Sounds alot like a Trifid cipher.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifid_cipher

Comment: Attacking this is very similar to attacking a many-time-pad. One advanced attack example: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse/127#127

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible i think. But if you consider evolving the encrypion system such as changing pair like  : "he","el","ll","lo","o" it would be way to easy to decrypt.