# RC4, finding key if we know plain text and ciphertext

Tags: known-plaintext-attack, rc4

Having plain text A , and  cipher text B. Can we somehow retrieve key , when we want to decrypt text C which was also crypted with the same key?

Comment: The keystream is just the xor of plain and ciphertext, so another text with the same key can also be decrypted "xor with that keystream again. $P_2 = C_2 \oplus (C_1 \oplus P_1)$.

Comment: so basicly doing B xor A i should retrieve the key to decrypt message C?

Comment: @trolkura RC4 keys are single use, since RC4 has no support for separate nonces. Using the same key means using the same key stream, which amounts to a many-time-pad. We have several, questions about many-time-pads, e.g. [Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer depends on whether you want to recover the *key* or the *keystream*. Let's first review how RC4 works:

### RC4 Recap

RC4 takes a key as input and generates a cryptographically secure stream of pseudo random numbers:

$KS= RC4(k)$

To encrypt a plaintext message M, we simply XOR it with the keystream KS:

$KS= RC4(k)$

$C= M \oplus KS$

To decrypt the ciphertext, we have to reproduce the keystream by providing the same shared key as input to RC4:

$M= C \oplus KS$

Now, it is cruical that the same keystream is never used twice for encryptoin, since an attacker could learn the XOR of the two messages:

$C1= M1 \oplus KS$

$C2= M2 \oplus KS$

$C1 \oplus C2= M1 \oplus KS \oplus M2 \oplus KS= M1 \oplus M2$

### Known-plaintext attacks against RC4

**RC4 keystream recovery**: This is a trivial thing to do once you are in possession of the plaintext:

$KS= C \oplus M$

This is normally not a problem since *no one that has basic understanding of cryptography uses the same keystream to encrypt multiple messages*. However, if I understand the description correctly, you have the following scenario:

$B= A \oplus RC4(K)$

$D= C \oplus RC4(K)$

If an attacker is in possession of A,B and D, it is trivial to extract the keystream generated by RC4(K) and decrypt the message C (at least up to the same length as A):

$C= D \oplus B \oplus A$

*Example:*

Let's say RC4 produces the following keystream:

```
KS= 11010110 00011010 01101011 10001110 11001101 11011111 01001010
```

With message A="hello" and C="secret!", you get the following ciphertexts:

```
A = 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 
C = 01110011 01100101 01100011 01110010 01100101 01110100 00100001 

B = 10111110 01111111 00000111 11100010 10100010
D = 10100101 01111111 00001000 11111100 10101000 10101011 01101011
```

By computing $A \oplus B$, you get the first 5 bytes of the keystream, which allows you to decrypt the first 5 bytes of C. Without the knowledge of the secret key or a longer plaintext-ciphertext pair you will not be able to decrypt the rest of C!

*Note*: You can already see in this example why it is a bad idea to re-use a keystream: the second byte of the ciphertexts of B and D are identical since they both encrypt the same character ("e").

**RC4 key recovery**: Recovering the secret key K is a much more difficult. There exist large classes of keys for which a small part of the secret key determines a large number of bits of the keystream. This is why it was recommended to throw away the first 256 bytes of the keystream (nowadays the recommendation is to **not use RC4 at all**). Observing enough plaintext/ciphertext pairs generated under a key can eventually be leveraged by attacks like the one by [Fluhrer et al.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluhrer,_Mantin_and_Shamir_attack), leading to the recovery of the key by an attacker.

Comment: What if Cipher text1 and cipher text2 differ in length?

Comment: @trolkura I added an example to illustrate different ciphertext lenghts :) You can basically only recover as much of the keystream as your plaintext-ciphertext pair is long! If the ciphertext you want to decrypt is shorter or equally long, you are good to go, a longer one can only be decrypted up to the length of the recovered keystream ;)