# How can I find the original message of two encrypted (Vernam Cipher) text without the key

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, one-time-pad, decryption

Can I get the steps or the solution if possible?
[image: problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've gotten the solution
After reading the following posts:

- [is it possible to get key in One time pad if key is reused?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61468/is-it-possible-to-get-key-in-one-time-pad-if-key-is-reused)
- [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse)
- [Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse)

and the answer of @Emme above/below, I came out with this solution:

Let M1 and M2 be the original messages.

`S1 ⊕ S2 = M1 ⊕ M2 since R is the same for S1 and S2`

**We calculate S1 ⊕ S2**

`S1 ⊕ S2 = 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1`

Since the language has just two words, `A` and `B`, I could guess the value of `M1` by taking a random combination of `A` and `B`.

`let M1 = AABBBA`. Converting `M1` gives `M1 = 111 111 0000 0000 0000 111`

let, `S1 ⊕ S2 = S3`. Then, `M1 ⊕ S3 = M2`

**We calculate M1 ⊕ S3**

`M1 ⊕ S3 = 111 0000 111 111 0000 0000`

Therefore, `M2 = M1 ⊕ S3 = 111 0000 111 111 0000 0000`

Decoding `M2` gives `M2 = ABAABB`

Therefore, `M1 = AABBBA` and `M2 = ABAABB`

### Proof

Remeber we said `S1 ⊕ S2 = M1 ⊕ M2 since R is the same for S1 and S2` 
If we calculate `M1 ⊕ M2`, we will have: 
 `111 111 0000 0000 0000 111 ⊕ 111 0000 111 111 0000 0000 = 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1` 
 Which is the same as `S1 ⊕ S2` as seen above

Answer (score 0):

You know that the two ciphertext you are given are formed as
$$C_1 = S_1 \oplus R\\C_2 = S_2 \oplus R$$ with the same $R$ in both cases.
So you can get rid of $R$ by calculating $$C^\ast = C_1 \oplus C_2 = S_1 \oplus S_2$$
Then you know that there are only two words, $111$ and $0000$. Thus, in $C^\ast$ $1$ can only occur if one sentence contains $A$ while the other contains $B$.
From there, since the two words have different lengths, you should be able to determine candidate sentences.